TypeError: Could not convert string to numeric during groupby mean operation in Pandas
I'm working on a data analysis project using Pandas to analyze housing prices in London boroughs. I'm trying to group the data by borough and year and then calculate the mean of the average housing prices. However, I'm encountering a TypeError that says it cannot convert a string to numeric.
Here’s a summary of what I’ve done so far:
Loaded the data from an Excel file.
Transposed the data and cleaned it up.
Melted the data so that each row represents a single observation (borough, date, price).
Filtered out rows with invalid borough names.
Converted the Average_price column to numeric.
Extracted the year from the Month column.
Attempted to group by borough and year to calculate the mean of Average_price.
It seems like there is some non-numeric data in the Average_price column, but I'm not sure why this is happening since I've converted it to numeric and dropped NaN values.
Could someone help me understand what might be going wrong and how I can fix it?
Thank you!
You can see the full code on GitHub.

Please add to your question the specific line that's failing along with a sample of data and expected output.
